# Reading an array from an array

Tags: c#, arrays

I'd like to pull a section of an array out for manipulation.

e.g. From an array that contains 50 items, i want to return items 12 to 22 in a new array

Im currently using LINQ which I am assuming is slow:

```
return fullArray.Skip(12).Take(22).ToArray();
```

Is there a quicker way?

Comment: Why are you assuming it's slow?

Comment: @Vijay He's assuming it, but I've tested it (for exactly this Take/Skip scenario) and it is orders of magnitude slower. I agree that he should have profiled first though :)

Comment: That's what I was kinda getting at, I know he said "assumed", but people do that all the time with linq and a lot of the time there is little to no difference in performance, at least nothing easily measurable!  I'll use this method instead of take/skip for my paging in the future :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Array.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.copy.aspx) method is massively quicker than Linq (I've tested it before and it was 2 or 3 orders of magnitude quicker!)

```
var sourceArray = object[50];
var newArray = object[10];
// Copy 10 elements, starting at index 12, to newArray (starting at index 0)
Array.Copy(sourceArray, 12, newArray, 0, 10);
```

Comment: Sorry, Im a bit of a n00b with arrays - thanks for the quick answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.Copy Method (Array, Int32, Array, Int32, Int32)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z50k9bft.aspx) method;

> Copies a range of elements from an Array starting at the specified
>   source index and pastes them to another Array starting at the
>   specified destination index. The length and the indexes are specified
>   as 32-bit integers.

For example;

```
int[] array1 = new int[50];
int[] array2 = new int[10];
Array.Copy(array1, 12, array2, array2.GetLowerBound(0), 10);
```

Comment: The reign of the downvoters is here it seems :) Not the first time an answer has been downvoted without reason.